# Why doesn't String* return all Strings?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, c++98

The following code is part of my project in C++98, therefore i'm not allowed to use vectors and such. Now the main use for this function is to break down a single string line, to an array of strings using the given `delimeter`, and the `size` is basically the number of words that i need to return. the problem is that when i debug and check `nums` towards the end, it changed it's size to 4, and only returned the first word, filled by every char of it.As if, `nums` is now `char*` i have changed the code many times, but i don't where i went wrong, any advice?

```
string* Split(string ss,char delimeter,int size)
{
    string *nums=new string[size];
    int index_c, index_sw=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j=0;j<ss.length();j++)
        {
            if (ss.at(j) == delimeter)
            {
                index_c = j;
                nums[i] = ss.substr(index_sw, index_c);
                index_sw += index_c;
                i++;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: C++98 had vectors.

Comment: `nums` is a pointer to the first element in the array. The debugger doesn't know how many elements it contains and can only safely assume it has 1.

Comment: `string *nums=new string[size],temp;` is a super bizarre way.

Comment: Your logic looks flawed here...your inner loop loops over the whole string and splits things up nicely, but you put every chunk into the same index of the array. Then you increment which index you'll be placing into and loop the whole string doing it all again.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for the outer loop or how you know size.

Comment: your premise is wrong. use `std::vector`, though that might not solve all the issues with your code

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: yes "for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)" can be replaced by "int i = 0;", and you do not only return the first word, but if you use a debugger that one only see "string *" and cannot know it is string[]

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not know the number of words in the `string ss` beforehand, you cannot specify `size` when calling the `Split` function. Not knowing `size` you will not be able to allocate memory to `nums`.

So you are better off using a `vector` of `string`s. As pointed out, `vector` is available in C++98.

Then your modified `Split` function will look like this:

```
vector<string> Split(string ss, char delimiter)
{
    vector<string> vs;
    int index_c, index_sw=0, j;

    for(j=0;j<ss.length();j++)
    {
        if (ss.at(j) == delimiter)
        {
            index_c = j;
            vs.push_back(ss.substr(index_sw, index_c - index_sw));                
            index_sw = index_c + 1;
        }
    }
    vs.push_back(ss.substr(index_sw, j - index_sw));        
    return vs;
}
```

which then can be called like this:

```
vector<string> ret = Split("This is a stackoverflow answer", ' ');
```

See demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/164067223d5fbbbb).